# Rails ActionCable undefined method `debug' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I am trying to implement ActionCable to rails 5.2.1 app. I added congif/cable.yml file because it was missing and I generated channel but shen I try to broadcast message from rails console using commant

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'comments:1', { asd: true }
```

it returns me error message:

```
undefined method `debug' for nil:NilClass
```

channels/comments_channel.rb

```
class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "comments:1"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

assets/javascripts/channels/comments.js

```
App.comments = App.cable.subscriptions.create("CommentsChannel", {
  connected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

config/cable.yml

```
development:
 adapter: redis
 url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

Comment: I guess the error points to a file and line number, right?

Comment: @arieljuod this is my full error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'debug' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):12`

Comment: @MišelAdemi That's not a full error. That't *one line* of the error. Can you please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52368799/edit) with the **full** error, and show which part of your code actually triggers this?

Comment: Since this seems to be a "vanilla" rails setup, it shouldn't be too hard to provide a [mcve] of the problem. How can I reproduce the error on my machine, from scratch?

Comment: @TomLord I run the code from console, so I run from console that one line and it return error to me.

Comment: OK @MišelAdemi, so what would be the complete reproduction steps for this? Run `rails new`, add a config file (??), then run that command from `rails console`?

Comment: @TomLord I added code a wrote for channel. Yes I added a config/cable.yml file and then from console I am trying to trigger broadcast message.

Comment: (1) You still haven't shown the `config/cable.yml` file. (2) You still haven't shown the full error.

Comment: @TomLord I added config file also, what you mean by full error, I showed you all lines console frints?

Comment: But at a glance, is the error simply that you haven't indented lines 2 and 3 in the `config/cable.yml` properly?

Comment: My guess is: Since the indentation is wrong, you haven't actually defined an `adapter`. And if you print the full stack trace, you'll see that there's a `nil` adapter object somewhere; and the library is trying to call `adapter.debug`, where `adapter == nil`.